# limit of a sum of a sequence

Tags: limits, riemann-sum

Compute the following limit or prove that it doesn't exist:

$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin \left(\frac{\pi k}{2 n}\right)\right]
$$

**Solution**

Note that the function $f(x)=\sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)$ is continuous and thus
integrable on $[0,1],$ and as it is increasing, then the limits is equal to the
upper sum, converges to the value of the integral
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin \left(\frac{\pi k}{2 n}\right)\right]$$

$$
=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[\sin \left(\frac{\pi k}{2 n}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{n}\right]$$

$$
=\int_{0}^{1} \sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right) d x$$

$$
=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin t d t$$

$$=\frac{2}{\pi}.$$

Can someone explain why it is equal to the upper sum?

Comment: it isn't homework it is from a test for previous years that I couldn't solve and to understand its solution I came here for help and to learn no trying to cheat

Comment: still you should show what you have tried for people to be motivated to look at your question. plus this *is* homework you have set yourself.

Comment: $\sin x$ is the imaginary part of $e^{ix}$. So the given expression can be computed explcitly using the formula for  geometric sum. Now do this much work and display it. Seek more help  if needed.

Comment: we haven't learned complex numbersI add the formal solution  I dont understand why it is equal to the upper sum ...

Comment: Can you use the formula for sum sines in arithmetic progression?

Comment: If you are going by Riemann sum then the answer should be obvious by the formula $$\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b-a} {n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(a+k\cdot\frac{b-a}{n}\right)$$ Your solution is based on this formula.

Comment: $\sin(x)$ is continuous, hence Riemann-integrable over any compact interval of the real line.

Answer (score 2):

You have done it right and it is a standard way. Otherwise you may do it as:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(ak)=\csc(a/2) \sin(an/2) \sin((1+n)a/2)\text{, where } a=\pi/(2n)$$

Then
$$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(\pi k/(2n))$$

So
$$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}~{\csc(\pi/(4n))}~ \sin(\pi/4) ~\sin(\pi/4+\pi/(4n))$$

$$
=\sin^2(\pi/4) \lim_{t\to 0}~ \frac{t}{\sin(t\pi/4)}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\frac{4}{\pi}=\frac{2}{\pi}.$$